# backbone firing the wrong router method

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I have 2 different content scenarios:

1. show a post with a dynamic url for instance:
   http://xyz.com/my-post-title-here
   http://xyz.com/2012/04/15/whatever
   .. and so on basically it can be anything
2. Show a predefined page for instance
   http://xyz.com/contact
   which could also be:
   http://xyz.com/contact/contact-form   <-- anything after /contact is an action to perform on the page.

My router conf looks like this,

```
{
""                 : "pageRoute" // homepage
"*post"            : "postRoute" //<--catchall for dynamic urls
"about*action"     : "pageRoute" // these
"contact*action"   : "pageRoute" // are
"gallery*action"   : "pageRoute" // all
"home*action"      : "pageRoute" // predefined
}
```

**PROBLEM** 
Only problem is that ONLY the postRoute method ever seems to get fired?

i've also tried:
"contact/:action"
"contact/*action"

but no luck.
I've read the documentation but I can't see my issue.

**EDIT:ANSWER** make the dynamic postroute the last in the config list thanks to @asawyer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the dynamic route the last one in the list.

Comment: OMG! why on earth have i been thinking that it was so important that it went first?.... that's it.. off to bed. THANK YOU